# Finding sequences and triggers associated with an Oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have used this query to fetch the list of sequences belonging to an Oracle database user:

```
SELECT * FROM all_sequences x,all_tables B
WHERE x.sequence_owner=B.owner AND B.TABLE_NAME='my_table';
```

But that database user is having many more sequence also, so the query returns me all the sequence of the database user. Can anybody help me to find the particular sequence of `my_table` using query so that I can get the auto increment id in my application.

Comment: A sequence isn't linked to a table directly, only indirectly via a trigger or an explicit insert statement (which may be in a stored procedure/package). Since you mention 'auto increment' presumably you're looking for a trigger that's setting the value; but then you don't need to know about it, the ID will be set automatically in the background. Unless you have a naming convention that relates the sequence name to the table name you'll need to search the trigger code (in `all_source`), if it's visible to you, and work out the table form that - easier to ask the other user, maybe?

Comment: Actually,i want the query which fetch list of table of my database user with the sequence and triggers used in the table.

Comment: @user2492525, there is *no way* to query which sequences are used for any table, because Oracle maintains no connection between them. Your application *might* use triggers to populate the ids, in which case Alex Poole's answer may be useful; or another application might not use triggers at all and call the sequence in the application code. Bottom line is, there is no generic solution to your problem.

Answer (score 19):

> i want the query which fetch list of table of my database user with the sequence and triggers used in the table

You can get the triggers associated with your tables from the `user_triggers` view. You can then look for any dependencies recorded for those triggers in `user_dependencies`, which may include objects other than sequences (packages etc.), so joining those dependencies to the `user_sequences` view will only show you the ones you are interested in.

Something like this, assuming you are looking at your own schema, and you're only interesting in triggers that references sequences (which aren't necessarily doing 'auto increment', but are likely to be):

```
select tabs.table_name,
  trigs.trigger_name,
  seqs.sequence_name
from user_tables tabs
join user_triggers trigs
  on trigs.table_name = tabs.table_name
join user_dependencies deps
  on deps.name = trigs.trigger_name
join user_sequences seqs
  on seqs.sequence_name = deps.referenced_name;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8da8/1).

If you're actually looking at a different schema then you'll need to use `all_tables` etc. and filter and join on the owner column for the user you're looking for. And if you want to include tables which don't have triggers, or triggers which don't refer to sequences, you can use outer joins.

---

Version looking for a different schema, though this assumes you have the privs necessary to access the data dictionary information - that the tables etc. are visible to you, which they may not be:

```
select tabs.table_name,
  trigs.trigger_name,
  seqs.sequence_name
from all_tables tabs
join all_triggers trigs
  on trigs.table_owner = tabs.owner
  and trigs.table_name = tabs.table_name
join all_dependencies deps
  on deps.owner = trigs.owner
  and deps.name = trigs.trigger_name
join all_sequences seqs
  on seqs.sequence_owner = deps.referenced_owner
  and seqs.sequence_name = deps.referenced_name
where tabs.owner = '<owner>';
```

If that can't see them then you might need to look at the DBA views, again if you have sufficient privs:

```
select tabs.table_name,
  trigs.trigger_name,
  seqs.sequence_name
from dba_tables tabs
join dba_triggers trigs
  on trigs.table_owner = tabs.owner
  and trigs.table_name = tabs.table_name
join dba_dependencies deps
  on deps.owner = trigs.owner
  and deps.name = trigs.trigger_name
join dba_sequences seqs
  on seqs.sequence_owner = deps.referenced_owner
  and seqs.sequence_name = deps.referenced_name
where tabs.owner = '<owner>';
```

Comment: @user2492525 - so why are you doing that? Why aren't you including the table/trigger/sequence names in the joins?

Comment: i just joined all this but my sequence name is different from my trigger name so it does not return me any value

Comment: @user2492525 - I'm not sure why that's an issue, the SQL Fiddle I linked to had different names. You just need to join on the appropriate name at each stage.

Comment: i solved the problem myself by using trigger body and which is having the sequence name .Using programming i split the sequence name and got it.Thank you all for helping to get my work done soon.

Answer (score 8):

One way  would be to run these queries to check if there are any `sequence`'s Pseudocolumns (`NEXTVAL` and `CURRVAL` ) used in your `functions` , `procedures`, `packages`, `Triggers` or `PL/SQL JAVA SOURCE`.

```
select * from user_source where 
         UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%NEXTVAL%';   

select * from all_source where 
         UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%NEXTVAL%';
```

Then go to the specific `Procedure, Function or Trigger` to check which column/table  gets populated by a sequence. 
The query could also be used  with `'%CURRVAL%'`

This might not help if you are running inserts from `JDBC` or other external applications using a `sequence`.

---

Oracle 12c introduced the `IDENTITY` columns, using which you could create a table with an identity column, which is generated by default.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, 
                   c2 VARCHAR2(10));
```

This will internally create a `sequence` that auto-generates the value for the table's column.So, If you would like to know which sequence generates the value for which table, you may query the `all_tab_columns`

```
SELECT data_default AS sequence_val
    ,table_name
    ,column_name
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE OWNER = 'HR'
    AND identity_column = 'YES';

SEQUENCE_VAL                             |TABLE_NAME               |COLUMN_NAME
-----------------------------------------|-------------------------------------
"HR"."ISEQ$$_78160".nextval              |T1                       |C1
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to this problem to guess the sequence of a particular sequence

```
select * from SYS.ALL_SEQUENCES where SEQUENCE_OWNER='OWNER_NAME' and LAST_NUMBER between (select max(FIELD_NAME) from TABLE_NAME) and (select max(FIELD_NAME)+40 from TABLE_NAME);
```

This query will guess by search the LAST_NUMBER of the sequence value between MAX value of the field using sequence and Max value + 40 (in my case cache value is 20, so I put 40)

Answer (score 1):

select SEQUENCE_NAME from sys.ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME' and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: This also only applies to identity columns, not other sequences, and specifically not sequence+trigger combinations - the 'ink' between a table and a sequence, in the old days anyway. The question is from just before Oracle 12c was released, so identity columns didn't exist yet.