# How to find sequnce name which associated to table with table name

Tags: oracle, sequence

How to find sequnce name which is associated to mytable in Oracle sql
Select * user_sequwnces where table_name =tablename

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49599887/266304) what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by a sequence being "associated to" a table? You may have an incorrect understanding of how sequences work. They are not attached to tables. Even when you create a new table with a system-generated identity column (for which a system generated and maintained sequence is created, to support this column), the automatically generated sequence is not "associated to" the table it was created for. For example, the same sequence may be used to populate the primary key of a different table.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a table using the IDENTITY clause, then the sequence name will aligned with the object ID of the table, eg

```
    SQL> create table t ( x int generated as identity);
    
    Table created.
    
    SQL> select object_id from user_objects
      2  where object_name = 'T';
    
     OBJECT_ID
    ----------
       4282429
    
    SQL> select sequence_name
      2  from   user_sequences
      3  where sequence_name like '%4282429%';
    
    SEQUENCE_NAME
    -----------------------------------------------------
    ISEQ$$_4282429
```

But if you just use a sequence of your own as a default, there is no such relationship, eg

```
SQL> create sequence blah;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table t1 ( x int default blah.nextval, y int );

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 ( x int default blah.nextval, y int );

Table created.

SQL> create table t3 ( x int default blah.nextval, y int );

Table created.
```

You can even drop the sequence ... and that only would become an issue later when you try to use it, eg

```
SQL> drop sequence blah;

Sequence dropped.

SQL> insert into t1 (x,y) values (0,0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t1 (y) values (0);
insert into t1 (y) values (0)
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```